# I am very new to Java, this being my second lesson in class. Could use any assistance

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Here is the code I'm trying to write:

```
// constants

    final static int NUMBERED_SURVEYED = 12467;
    final static double PURCHASED_ENERGY_DRINKS = 0.14;
    final static double PREFER_CITRUS_DRINKS = 0.64;
    public class simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Variables
    double energyDrinkers = calculateEnergyDrinkers(NUMBERED_SURVEYED);
    double preferCitrus = calculatePreferCitrus(NUMBERED_SURVEYED);

    // Display the results.
    System.out.println("Total number of people surveyed " + NUMBERED_SURVEYED);
    System.out.println("Appoximately " + energyDrinkers + " bought at least one energy drink");
    System.out.println(preferCitrus + " of those " + "prefer citrus flavored energy drinks.");
    }

/**
* Caculate the number of energy drinkers.
*
* @param numberSurveyed
* @return
*/
public static double calculateEnergyDrinkers(int numberSurveyed) {
    return numberSurveyed * PURCHASED_ENERGY_DRINKS;
    }
/**
* Calculate the number of energy drinkers that prefer citrus flavor.
*
* @param numberSurveyed
* @return 
*/
public static double calculatePreferCitrus(int numberSurveyed) {
    return numberSurveyed * PREFER_CITRUS_DRINKS; 
    }
}
```

I am getting 3 error messages. I am using an online compiler.

/simple.java:3: error: class, interface, or enum expected
final static int NUMBERED_SURVEYED = 12467;
             ^
/simple.java:4: error: class, interface, or enum expected
final static double PURCHASED_ENERGY_DRINKS = 0.14;
             ^
/simple.java:5: error: class, interface, or enum expected
final static double PREFER_CITRUS_DRINKS = 0.64;
             ^
3 errors

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the fields inside the class

```
public class simple {
    final static int NUMBERED_SURVEYED = 12467;
    final static double PURCHASED_ENERGY_DRINKS = 0.14;
    final static double PREFER_CITRUS_DRINKS = 0.64;
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is named simple.java, your class/interface/enum must be the root object:

```
 public class simple {
 // all code you wrote here
 }
```

A file is composed by:

package declaration;

import statement;

type declaration (your 'public type name'), inside the type you declare methods for your object

static type declarations (to declare another types of objects inside the same file);

Comment: The file starts with the package and imports usually. They declared the fields outside of the class though.

Comment: He is probably using notepad, so he's not using packages, sorry not mentioning that

Comment: Yes, I am using NotePad++.

Comment: Add your code in place of the comment I added in my code answer